How to open a file from Uri in Android?
I want to open a file from storage then read content and handle data further.
I added permission to AndroidManifest.xml
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

I tried to find guide from Android but it just let me know about name of file or size
text
Currently, I copy file to /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/[my.package.path] and open by name but my application need to use file from user choosing.
file = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null), FILE_NAME);
Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(file));


Use the Storage Access Framework (ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT / ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument). With the Uri that you receive, use ContentResolver and openInputStream() to get an InputStream on the content to pass to WorkbookFactory.create(). FWIW, I cover using ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument in this chapter of this free book.
